# Compactness of multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compactness of  Multiplication Operator on $L^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51788/compactness-of-multiplication-operator-on-l2)

Let $u: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded continuous function. Show that the multiplication operator $M_u$ defined on $L^2(\mathbb{R)}$ by $$M_uf =uf$$  cannot be compact on $L^2(\mathbb{R)}$ unless $u = 0$. And also that the same holds when $u\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

I cannot think of some clever way of choosing the compact functions from the unit ball, such that there is no convergent subsequence of $(u(x)f_n(x))$

Comment: The answer to this question covers yours to a large extent: [Compactness of Multiplication Operator on $L^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/51788)