# Boundedness of non-compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

In my notes we stated that the following operator is bounded but not compact. Can someone give a short proof of it?

$T:L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1])$ given by $(Tf)(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}f(x)$

Comment: do I am right? we are looking for the operator norm, i.p.: $\vert\vert Tf \vert\vert_{L^2} \leq M \vert\vert f \vert \vert_{L^2}$

Comment: yes. That's correct

Comment: But isn't it enough to consider the frac $1/x+1$? which is bounded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compactness of  Multiplication Operator on $L^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51788/compactness-of-multiplication-operator-on-l2)

Comment: but the old post does not contain anything about boundedness

Comment: well what is an upper bound for $\int |Tf|^2$? You wrote your self that $1/(1+x)$ is bounded.

Comment: an upper bound is: $\int \vert f \vert^2$

Comment: correct ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: and could you please loose some words for compactness?

Comment: the answer in the other post is quite extensive.